# TabControl Cancel change of tabs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using `TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` event when the user change tabs. The `TabControl.SelectedIndex` / `TabControl.SelectedTab` return only the new tab. Is there any way I can get the previous tab? Or must I stick with the obvious store the current tab every time I change tabs?

I want to use this to cancel a change of tabs under certain conditions, like there is unsaved changes.

Comment: You will have to store it on every change... at the begining of `SelectedIndexChange` you just store it... There is no other way :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to cancel the change of a tab, you can use the `Deselecting` event. There you can cancel the change by setting property `Cancel` of the provided `TabControlCancelEventArgs` to true.

Comment: And use `Selecting` if you want to preview the tab about to be selected, and want to be able to cancel it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

There are events better suited for what you want to do.

Comment: `TabControl_Deselecting` is exactly what I was seaching for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I used tabControl Selected method to prevent users selecting a certain tab, in other word, to disable a tab page.

```
TabPage currentPage;

private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPage == tabNotAllowed)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = currentPage;
        MessageBox.Show("You cannot use the tab you selected.");
    }
    else
    {
        currentPage = e.TabPage;
    }
}
```